# Click on url bar without reload the browser

Tags: html, single-page-application, html5-history

Is it possible to activate the `history.pushState(...)` method if someone click on the URL bar and press enter, and preventing reload of the page?

Comment: You try to interfere between a user and it's browser? That is not funny at all...

Comment: Mhh. For example I saw pages like gitlab (which obviously are single-page-apps) where you can write `https://gitlab.com/dashboard` in the url bar and the correct page is loaded. Another example is angular-js where you can set the html5 mode to true and the hash is away.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent the user from reloading the page if they want to do so. However, you can interpret the URL whichever way you want, so when the page is loaded, check the URL path from your single page app, and route the request to whatever controller is relevant.

This is what gitlab is actually doing.

Comment: Ok, I think I have found a solution. It was just a flaw. Thanks anyway.